# How do you set the header to "Accept" application/json in dojo.store.JsonRest when putting or posting?

Tags: dojo

How do you set the header "Accept" value to application/json in  dojo.store.JsonRest when putting or posting?

```
var dataStore = new dojo.store.JsonRest({
    target : "/project-services/"
});

dataStore.put({id: 10, field1: "Some Value", field2: "Other Value"});
```

The header sent is currently:

Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the header information is not an option for PUT and POST so I decided to simply extend dojo.store.JsonRest.

```
/**
 * Extend the dojo.store.JsonRest
 */

if(!dojo._hasResource["ext.store.JsonRest"]) {
    dojo._hasResource["ext.store.JsonRest"] = true;
    dojo.provide("ext.store.JsonRest");
    dojo.require("dojo.store.JsonRest");
    dojo.extend(dojo.store.JsonRest, {
        put: function(object, options){
            options = options || {};
            var id = ("id" in options) ? options.id : this.getIdentity(object);
            var hasId = typeof id != "undefined";
            return dojo.xhr(hasId && !options.incremental ? "PUT" : "POST", {
                    url: hasId ? this.target + id : this.target,
                    postData: dojo.toJson(object),
                    handleAs: "json",
                    headers:{
                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                        , "If-Match": options.overwrite === true ? "*" : null
                        , "If-None-Match": options.overwrite === false ? "*" : null
                        , "Accept": "application/javascript, application/json"
                    }
                });
        },
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today and ended up with a workaround like yours. PEM in #dojo suggested I make a trac entry for it, so hopefully it'll be fixed some time in the near future [bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/12826](http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/12826).